# Simple PHP array codeigniter controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, controller

I would like to shorten my CodeIgniter controller a bit.
Now it looks like this:

```
case 'klant1':
                $data['title'] = $page;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('pages/klant1', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
                break;
case 'klant2':
                $data['title'] = $page;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('pages/klant2', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
                break;
case 'klant3':
                $data['title'] = $page;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('pages/klant3', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
                break;
```

I guess there could be a way to use an array or something that makes `klant1 + 2 + 3` ?

Could someone help me out with the code? I don't think its hard, but I'm not good with php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
function view($page = 'home', $klant = null) {
case 'klant':
                $data['title'] = $page;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $loadpage = 'pages/klant'.$klant;
                $this->load->view($loadpage, $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
                break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$klan = your_case;    

$data['title'] = $page;    
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);    
$this->load->view('pages/'.$klan, $data);    
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data)
```

Comment: 'your_case' ? is this some kind of a php function or do I have to change this to something?

Comment: replace your switch case with my code

• your_case is not a php function (;___;).

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
switch($variable)
{
...your code
```

to

```
$data['title'] = $page;    
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);    
$this->load->view('pages/'.$variable, $data);    
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'klant1':
    $load = 'klant1';
    break;
case 'klant2':
    $load = 'klant2';
    break;
case 'klant3':
    $load = 'klant3';
    break;

$data['title'] = $page;

$this->load->vars($data);

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('pages/' . $load);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```